# Passing an arbritrary JavaScript object in Xul

Tags: javascript, xul

I'm following [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/working_with_windows_in_chrome_code#Example_5.3a_Using_nsIWindowWatcher_for_passing_an_arbritrary_JavaScript_object) to pass an object to a window, but when it as an argument it's with "undefined" value.

This is my first window (obs. **dump** is the way to print to console when [debug options](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Debugging) are turned on):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>

<!DOCTYPE window SYSTEM "chrome://XulWindowArgTest/locale/XulWindowArgTest.dtd">

<window id="windowID" width="400" height="300"
    xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

    <script>
        <![CDATA[
            function onClickMe(event) {
                dump("begin\n");

            try {
                var args = {
                  param1: true,
                  param2: 42
                };
                args.wrappedJSObject = args;

                var watcher = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/embedcomp/window-watcher;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowWatcher);
                watcher.openWindow(null, "chrome://XulWindowArgTest/content/about.xul", "windowName", "chrome", args);

            } catch (e) {
                dump("error: " + e + "\n");
            }


                dump("end\n");
            }
        ]]>
    </script>

    <button label="Click me !" oncommand="onClickMe();" />

</window>
```

and my second window:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>

<!DOCTYPE window SYSTEM "chrome://XulWindowArgTest/locale/XulWindowArgTest.dtd">

<window xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
    onload="onload()">

    <script>
        <![CDATA[
            function onload() {
                dump('arg = ' + window.arguments[0].wrappedJSObject + "\n");
            }
        ]]>
    </script>

    <label value="test" />

</window>
```

when the second window loads, it calls the onload and prints:

> arg = undefined

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually call openDialog and therefore can just pass one or more parameters without using a watcher... but from the example you are trying to follow, it seems that you left out this line:

```
args.wrappedJSObject = args;
```

If you are trying to do it all inline perhaps you should be passing:

```
{wrappedJSOBject:["myarg"]}
```

Additionally, in your second window you are trying to print

```
window.arguments[0].wrappedJSObjectarg
```

when your example is referencing

```
window.arguments[0].wrappedJSObject;
```

I'm assuming the former error is an oversight and the latter is a typo.

---

Also, you might need to make sure that you aren't checking the arguments until after the window is loaded -- check them in a function called by the onload attribute of the window.

Comment: About the openDialog approach, I've tried with that first example on the page: `openDialog(null, "chrome://XulWindowArgTest/content/about.xul", "windowName", "chrome", {status: "Reading remote data", maxProgress: 50, progress: 10} );` and read with `dump('arg = ' + window.arguments[0].maxProgress + "\n");` but it either prints `undefined`

Comment: Also, thanks for the corrections. Unfortunately, it's still printing `undefined`. I've updated the question with your appointments.

Comment: @Tom Brito, openDialog has different parameters than .open, so you would need to remove that null parameter, I believe, for that function call to actually work.  With that said, I have a version of the code from your question that is working here.  I'm not clear on why your version is returning undefined.  Actually, you are sending your entire object to debug() -- i'm not sure how it handles that; I use jsdump and it just tells me it is an object.  printing window.argument[0].wrappedJSObject.param2 might be a better choice for you.

Comment: See also the note I appended to my answer re: window load timing.

Comment: I am using the onload, as you can see in the second window code.. :)

Comment: I've read the openDialog doc now, and using `openDialog("chrome://XulWindowArgTest/content/about.xul", "windowName", "chrome", {status: "Reading remote data"} );` and in the other window reading `dump('arg = ' + window.arguments[0].status + "\n");` it shows `undefined` here.. I don't know why either.. strange that it works for you..

Comment: what right now worked for me, was to use [xpcom singleton component](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/working_with_windows_in_chrome_code#Using_an_XPCOM_singleton_component), so, consider it solved, thanks for the wasting time with it :) Tell me any new ideas, I still have the sample code to make new tests and learn more about.

Comment: Oops, I missed that onload call in your window.  Sorry, not sure what to make of that.  I would also check to see if window.arguments[0] is defined to anything.  Perhaps you have a typo somewhere?

Comment: @pc1oad1etter No, my example is just as pasted in the question body. By the way, I'm using Xul 1.9.0.2 in Ubuntu 10.04.